# Is it possible to create a Triggered Send Definition using WSProxy?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, triggered-send

I want to create a Triggered Send Definition using **"createItem"** method under **WSProxy** . However i am unable to find any example on the same . I am fairly new to using APIs and need to refer to some working example in order to understand the flow . Can someone please point me in right direction?

Comment: Are you wanting to send a triggered send email or just create a definition?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs - Yes, I want to create a Triggered Send definition

Answer (score 3):

It's nicely explained in [Send a triggered email using WSProxy](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/10/22/send-a-triggered-email-using-wsproxy/) article from sfmarketing.cloud blog.

`Triggered Send` object:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Header>
    <fueloauth>YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN</fueloauth>
 </Header>
 <Body>
   <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSend">
      <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
      <TriggeredSendDefinition>
       <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
       <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
       <CustomerKey>Definition_Key</CustomerKey>
      </TriggeredSendDefinition>
      <Subscribers>
       <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
       <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
       <EmailAddress>email@test.com</EmailAddress>
       <SubscriberKey>email@test.com</SubscriberKey>
       <Attributes>
         <Name>firstname</Name>
         <Value>John</Value>
       </Attributes>
      </Subscribers>
    </Objects>
   </CreateRequest>
 </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Script using `craeteItem` function:

> To create a new TriggeredSend, we will use the [`createItem`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_create.htm) WSProxy
>   function, which has three parameters:
>
> - The first parameter is the object type to perform the action on –
>     here, we will use previously mentioned `TriggeredSend` object
> - The second
>     parameter is a JavaScript object which represents the fields and
>     values to set on the object when created – in below example, we will
>     call it `tsDef` and use it to define the `CustomerKey`, `Subscribers` and
>     optionally, their `Attributes`
> - The third parameter is optional and
>     includes any properties to be set using the SOAP CreateOptions object

```
<script runat="server">       
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var tsExKey = ''; //provide Triggered Send External Key
var EmailAddress = ''; //pass Email Address
var SubscriberKey = ''; //pass Subscriber Key
var firstName = ''; //pass First Name
var lastName = ''; //pass Last Name
var tsDef = {
    TriggeredSendDefinition: {
        CustomerKey: tsExKey
    },
    Subscribers: [{
        EmailAddress: EmailAddress,
        SubscriberKey: SubscriberKey,
        Attributes: [{
            Name: 'firstName',
            Value: firstName
        }]
    }]
};
var res = prox.createItem('TriggeredSend', tsDef);      
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @przemyslaw, Thanks for your input. However this example does not explain how to "Create" a Triggered Send Definition using WsProxy. My requirement is to create a TSD from a cloud page.Can you give me some pointers on that?